# PDFBox best java version

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, out-of-memory, pdfbox

I am using pdfbox(2.0.19) in a web app (spring app on tomcat), and i had some memory issues (high consumption, a 5 page pdf 700KB, would cause the memory to go up to 800MB from 250MB ), this was using openjdk8, but when i changed to openjdk11, the memory consumption decreased to 490MB~500MB.

Basically, i download pdfs from the web as byte[], then pass these byte[]s to a function which open each as PDDocument, and merge these pages to new PDDocument. (I know all are in memory, but even if i wrote the downloaded files to disk would it make a difference)

My question is , is there a recommended JDK version to use with pdfbox(2.0.19), and if there is any configuration or GC params that i should consider to optimize the memory consumption as much as i can ?

Comment: I'm a PDFBox committer and I have no recommendations, except to use the latest version (i.e. the latest jdk8, or the latest jdk11 etc). Additionally see this: https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/faq.html#im-getting-an-outofmemoryerror-what-can-i-do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Tilman Hausherr mentioned in the comment above, using the latest version of pdfbox, jdk, ... etc is recommended and has huge impact on the memory consumption and overall performance.

For the in-memory vs write-to-disk part:

- Using `scratchFile` for opening the `PDDocument` was the best as compared to in-memory or write-to-disk approaches.